# Find the mean and variance

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume the total number of claims $N$ in a given year faced by an insurance company is a random
variable following a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$. Assume the amount of claims$ Y_1, Y_2,...$,
are independent random variables having the same mean $\mu$  and variance 
$\sigma^2$
. Also assume that
the total number of claims and the claim sizes are independent. Let $S =
\Sigma_{i=1}^N Y_i
$
 be the total
amount of the claims faced by the insurance company during the given year. Find the mean and
variance of $S$.

Comment: Could you add what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Jerry I have no idea since $S$ involves many variables.

Comment: Really? In my experience $N$ isn't THAT big. Most numbers are bigger than it! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S$ has a compound poisson distribution. See the link below. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution